# Как получить из базы данных Firebase данные о конкретном пользователе

Tags: java, android, firebase

Есть база данных Firebase в которую я во время регистрации вбиваю некоторые данные, они попадают в раздел Users под ключом UID из Auth:

```
public void writeUserToDB(Object data, String currentUser){
        DatabaseReference myRef = mDataBase.child("Users/" + currentUser);
        myRef.setValue(data);
    }


mRegisterBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Переменные для регистрации
                String id = mDataBase.getKey();
                String name = mName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String userBinder = mUserBinder.getText().toString().trim();

                //Проверка условий регистрации
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Введите почту...");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    mEmail.setError("Введите пароль...");
                    return;
                }
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    mName.setError("Введите имя...");
                    return;
                }
                if (password.length() < 8) {
                    mPassword.setError("Пароль должен состоять из 8-ми символов.");
                    return;
                }

                //Регистрация пользователя
                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override

                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            User newUser = new User(currentUser, id, name, email, password, userBinder);

                            //Запись нового пользователя в базу данных
                            currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            writeUserToDB(newUser, currentUser);

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Пользователь зарегистрирован.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Произошла ошибка. Повторите." +
                                    task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

[image: Как загруженные данные выглядят в БД]

Необходимо получать эти данные в MainActivity в виде переменных String, чтобы использовать при нажатии другой кнопки.
Как в MainActivity и где (в OnCreate или в ButtonListener) написать listener, который получит данные по uid из Firebase и преобразует их в переменные для последующего использования.
Вопрос от новичка.
Отредактировано:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
        mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference uidRef = mDataBase.child("Users/").child(uid);
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String email = ds.child("email").getValue(String.class);
                    String userBinder = ds.child("userBinder").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("TAG", email + "/" + userBinder);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
            }
        };
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: Для меня загадка почему все новички используют устаревшую Realtime Database, вместо молодежной модной  Cloud Firestore. А по вопросу - получают эти данные, как и любые другие - через ссылку на базу и дочерние элементы списка (тут как раз потребуется UID). Не забудьте защитить пользователей, задав rules в базе

Comment: @Михаил я написал код, но он не работает, куда я могу его написать, чтобы Вы увидили?

Comment: Приложи код в описание задачи.

Comment: @Михаил прикрепил код. Он не работает и у него другая функция, это что-то вроде "прототипа". Надеюсь на вашу помощь, из бд мне надо получать эти данные и использовать в другом методе этого же класса.

Comment: На вид нормальный код, только "Users/" слэш лишний. Тебе нужно дебажить - проверить что ссылка на базу не null, что uid который ты полочил существует в базе, что onDataChange срабатывает и в dataSnapshot что то приходит. Проверить rules в базе..